# Using puppet to manage incrontab

Tags: puppet, incrontab

Puppet has the `cron` resource for managing the crontab, but is there a similar way of managing `incrontab`? I can find no writings anywhere regarding this, and to be fair, I'm extremely new to puppet (software dev helping out an overworked sysadmin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no native support for `incron` but that doesn't mean you can't write a simple defined type that manages the tabs in `/etc/incron.d`. These would be just `file` resources for which Puppet has of course native support. Depending on your specific needs you could also make that defined type more complex by adding support for per-user `incrontabs`. These would probably require use of the [Concat module](https://github.com/ripienaar/puppet-concat).

But have a look at https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_defined_types.html first for more info on defined types. Could be that's all you need.

Comment: excuse my ignorance, but I have an incron line added to the incrontab, but nothing at all in /etc/incron.d/ .. if a file with a single line is added to the incron.d folder, should it load up as an incrontab ?

Comment: Yes, system incrontabs are loaded and watched by `incrond`. I don't personally use or know much of incron, I just read http://linux.die.net/man/5/incrontab which states that system incrontabs are in `/etc/incron.d` and user incrontabs are created by means of incrontab and put in `/var/spool/incron`. So your Puppet type/module would put system incrontabs in `/etc/incron.d` and a user's incrontab in `/var/spool/incron/<username>`.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a `incron` module at https://github.com/duritong/puppet-incron.

I have a pending pull request that adds a `incron::watch` defined type. It's working fine for me so far.